# Google Pagespeed Insight test fails on fast website with NO_FCP error, is there a way to fix it?

Tags: three.js, google-pagespeed

im working on a site where I use three.js for 3d content, I've made it work with relative paths, loads way faster than from unpkg or other 3rd party. However, when I try to measure the pagespeed with google pagespeed insight it fails with the NO_FCP error code. I have read that thats the response for slow websites if they fail to load in under 15 seconds, but as anybody can check it (at least in europe) the page loads pretty fast: https://adambernath.com/lotto/lotto.html

The only thing here that I do use which differs from other pages i build usually is three.js, I have no other idea what could cause this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Low probability answer

Possibly this is caused by a bug in Lighthouse at the moment where it is trying to detect libraries.

If you look in your server logs you should see a request for "https://adambernath.com/asset-manifest.json" which returns a 500 error on your server.

If you fix that to return a 404 it may fix the issue.

### More likely

It is known that [Chromium and Lighthouse have problems with full WebGL rendered pages.](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/11213)

Give it some time and it will probably get resolved. For now I would resort to using a performance trace using the "performance" tab, with Network set to "fast 3g" and CPU set to "4x slowdown".

This will give you the raw data that lighthouse uses and let you spot bottlenecks etc. Obviously the down side is it is a lot harder to understand so you may need to do some googling!

Even then you may not get FCP and LCP as I have had mixed results when I tested this for you, but those are just arbitrary measures, the Performance tab will tell you all you need to know from the screenshot timeline and from the CPU usage (long tasks).

Performance wise - my first reaction would be to use `gzip` or `br` on your "fgoly.gltf" file - it currently does not look like it is compressed at all and represents 70% of the page weight at the moment.

Comment: yeah, the problem is partially solved by adding more stuff to the page (totally weird), but the pagespeed insight still gives a questionmark result. Try this page:
https://adambernath.com/lotto/test.html

Comment: Yes so the browser (as this is partially browser timings related) now sees the images and knows when there is something painted. However your numbers will be skewed a bit as it won't take rendering time of the canvas into consideration properly (but will still take JS execution time into effect so it won't be far off). It will mis-report the item and timing for FCP and LCP probably but not much you can do I am afraid. Focus on the suggestions under "diagnostics" and "opportunities" rather than the score itself. So minimise crtical request depth, compress as I said, etc. etc.

Comment: I see, thank you. I've tested it with lighthouse and the scores seem to be pretty okay, except performance where it fails on LCP. As pagespeed also factors in ranking, and as there is no clear indication from google how they factor in when giving a site "their score" to rank the page, I guess the safest is to leave three js out of the picture completely... as this sites success will only rely on page ranking. I can easily reach 100/100 score if I dont use three js... any experience with googles 3d maybe as an alternative? https://modelviewer.dev this one

Comment: seems like they also "fail" (well, not a good score) on their own test with 3d:
https://adambernath.com/lotto/fail.png

Comment: For your design why not fake 3D with a multi layered parallax design. That could be made really light weight, especially if you can get the desired image effect with SVG. A 5 layer parallax with some slight manipulation of the z (i think i mean z-axis, basically a slight rotation around y-axis, I always have to fiddle to remember!) would look 99% and you could probably do the whole thing (images and all) for less weight than the three.js library alone, nevermind your model file etc.

Comment: yes, I was thinking about that as an option, Ive tried it earlier on a different site, and even with everything optimized (requestanimationframe for every interaction) it starts to suffer on the scroll performance after adding 2 layers of parallax, and this would need around 4-5 layers. i will probably design something else instead

Comment: do you know how to write an asset manifest? This is the first time i heard of it, I looked it up and im a little bit confused about it, I'm not even sure why is there a request for it (probably the three.js packages triggers the request) but the three.js package doesnt have an asset manifest json, so I dont really know where to start with it.

Comment: i answered that part in the answer bud, it is a bug with Lighthouse when it runs its test for vulnerable libraries, just make sure the site returns a 404 instead of a 500 as it currently does and then you can ignore it.

Comment: this is an area which im absolutely alien to (its php isnt it?) can you help me how to do that 500 to 404?

Answer (score 0):

Your .gltf file is taking a very long time to load.
I am not sure why, as it is not large. Best to start investigating that. Are you generating it on the fly or something?
Why are you even using a .gltf model when it seems you just need spheres with textures?

[image]

[image]

It looks like you are using cloudflare, maybe some setting in cloudflare is not correct? (I have never used cloudflare).
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about why the gltf "loads" so slow either, its not big, and when you see how it renders, its actually renders in a maximum of 3-4 seconds

I use gltf for the sphere because its incredibly hard to position them in the shape I wanted them without a manipulator (so i positioned them in maya), i guess some time is worth spending on it if it solves the problem

cloudlflare setting should be okay, I use the same settings for every website i build and other sites Ive built can get 100/100 score.

Comment: Checking again this morning and the .gltf file loads in just over 2 seconds... so I am not sure what happened yesterday.

Comment: I think chrome and google confuses the whole 3d thing, sometimes they get stuck on the fact that a 3d scene needs calculations after the scene is already loaded